# simple method/extendable class to make my toString method of a POJO output json like output?

Tags: java, json, jersey

I have a number of pojos which are being used for a jersey client to be filled with the JSON data from a restful call.  The client is reading in json and filling these objects using the JacksonJsonProvider. I'm not using any annotations, the variable names are equal to the json coming in.

I would like the toStrng methods for these PoJos to automatically output a representation of the json they represent, without my having to manually write each toString.  Since these are basic POJO which are structured in a simlpe tree format it should be realatively easy to output these pojo as json in the toString method.  In fact I know I could use reflection to do this myself in some parent/abstract class if I felt like it.  However, it feels like I shouldn't have to do this by hand.  Is there already some method out there that will do this for me I can use instead?

I don't insist that the output be json, though that would be preferable, but any similar method of visualizing the variables automatically without my manually writing it would be fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) you can serialize objects into JSON. Your `toString()` would then look something like:

```
public String toString() {
    return StaticLib.GSON.toJson(this);
}
```

A GSON object can be shared across all objects, hence my inclusion of this mystery `StaticLib` class. You can find the correct name or place for that in your own project I'm sure.

Comment: Would you please let me know the import statement for StaticLib, since I am not able to find it in gson.jar.

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti `StaticLib` was supposed to refer to a static class you create that holds the global instance of the `GSON` object you want to use throughout your project.